# 65 years old <or/and> <older/higher/greater>

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I saw **65 years old or older** used by reliable sources such as the New York Times. Does "old" and "older" sound repetitive, or is it just the way to say it? Would it be better to use "65 years old or **higher**" or "65 years old or **greater**"?

Also, for this graph, should I use "65 years old **or** older" or "65 years old **and** older"?

> 1n 1940 approximately 7% of Sweden’s population was 65 years old **or/and**
> **older/higher/greater**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic choices of preposition are:

- 65 years and *over*
- 65 years and *above*
- 65 years *plus* (maybe also styled as '65+')
- 65 years and *older*

'Greater' and 'higher' are simply just not idiomatic when speaking about age, although you can use 'higher' when referring back to the group (eg "the higher age groups"), it just isn't natural to call the group by that.

Which you use from among the idiomatic choices is up to you, unless you are working with a style guide.

As to the question of 'or/and' - this depends on whether you are presenting an option or not. For example:

1. You can enter the bar if you are 18 *or* over.
2. This bar is for those aged 18 *and* over.

In example 1, an individual ('you') is referred to. They can only be one age, so they must be 18 *or* over. Example 2 refers, not to an individual, but to anyone that can enter the bar - those aged 18 *and* those aged over 18. Your specific example is referring to a group, so use 'and'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Does **65 years plus** include those who are 65? The graph is about those 65 and over so I'm not sure if **65 years plus** is appropriate for this graph.

Comment: @Learner110 Yes it does.

Comment: "65 years old or more" would be possible, but not 'higher' or 'greater'.

Comment: You also see "...and up", especially when talking about childhood ages; as in "This game is safe for kids age 6 and up."